# Disable zoom of mpbile device, input field

Tags: gwt, mobile, input

Is it possible to diasble the zoom/focus of and input field?

when touch a Textbox with my mobile device it automaticle zooms and focus in...

Answer (score 0):

been looking for this answer as well. people keep suggesting to change the input font-size to 16px but that does not work.

Comment: i did it by changeing the Viewport dynamicly : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254023/gwt-change-meta-tag      Or for in Javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170308/javascript-change-meta-values